# Does anyone know which source Anthony Kenny used for Parmenides in A History of Western Philosophy?

Tags: ontology, translation, presocratics, parmenides, sources

Reading his textbook, his extracts of Parmenides are much more readable than the other translations I've come across, but he only seems to source them by Diels-Kratz number!

In case anyone recognises the translation of these extracts they are:

> What you can call and think must Being be For Being can, and nothing cannot, be

> Never shall this prevail, that Unbeing is; Rein in your mind from any thought like this.

> Unbeing you won’t grasp—it can’t be done— Nor utter; being thought and being are one.

Comment: According to [Schofield's review](https://www.lrb.co.uk/the-paper/v27/n04/malcolm-schofield/not-not-to-be), Kenny makes his own (liberal) translations. "When quoting Lucretius, Kenny sometimes uses the partial Dryden translation, which has led him to try his own hand" at Parmenides's poem..